# No wifi adapter found!

Tags: wireless

Looks like the hardware is Realtek Semiconductor RTL8821CE.

There's no wifi icon at top but a question mark instead.

I see

> no wifi adapter found, make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and
>   turned on

when I click wifi in settings.

Comment: Type `RTL8821CE` into the search box ("`Search on Ask Ubuntu...`")

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I highly recommend that you review https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and then return here and [edit] your post to include necessary information. That way we don't have to guess if the hardware is what it looks like among other useful details. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your wifi adapter? After a recent kernel upgrade, upon boot no wifi. After checking discovered, as you did "no wifi adapter found". So I removed that one and installed another one.
Check for recommended adapter, such as Edimax N 150.